# Why is sapply relatively slow when querying attributes on variables in a data.frame?

Tags: r

Something that kind of surprised me: let's compare two ways of getting the `class`es for variables in a big data frame with many columns: an `sapply` solution and a `for` loop solution.

```
bigDF <- as.data.frame( matrix( 0, nrow=1E5, ncol=1E3 ) )
library( microbenchmark )

for_soln <- function(x) {
  out <- character( ncol(x) )
  for( i in 1:ncol(x) ) {
    out[i] <- class(x[,i])
  }
  return( out )
}

microbenchmark( times=20,
  sapply( bigDF, class ),
  for_soln( bigDF )
)
```

gives me, on my machine,

```
Unit: milliseconds
                  expr       min        lq    median       uq      max
1      for_soln(bigDF)  21.26563  21.58688  26.03969 163.6544 300.6819
2 sapply(bigDF, class) 385.90406 405.04047 444.69212 471.8829 889.6217
```

Interestingly, if we transform `bigDF` into a list, `sapply` is once again nice and speedy.

```
bigList <- as.list( bigDF )
for_soln2 <- function(x) {
  out <- character( length(x) )
  for( i in 1:length(x) ) {
    out[i] <- class( x[[i]] )
  }
  return( out )
}

microbenchmark( sapply( bigList, class ), for_soln2( bigList ) )
```

gives me

```
Unit: milliseconds
                    expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
1     for_soln2(bigList) 1.887353 1.959856 2.010270 2.058968 4.497837
2 sapply(bigList, class) 1.348461 1.386648 1.401706 1.428025 3.825547
```

Why are these operations, especially `sapply`, taking so much longer with a `data.frame` as compared to a `list`? And is there a more idiomatic solution?

Comment: Note that this is size dependent. On my machine if I change the number of rows to 1000 then `sapply(bigDF, class)` takes less time than `for_soln(bigDF)` .

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`edit:` The old proposed solution `t3 <- sapply(1:ncol(bigDF), function(idx) class(bigDF[,idx]))` is now changed to `t3 <- sapply(1:ncol(bigDF), function(idx) class(bigDF[[idx]]))`. Its even faster. Thanks to `@Wojciech`'s comment

The reason I could think of is that you are converting the data.frame to a list unnecessarily. In addition, your results are also not identical

```
bigDF <- as.data.frame(matrix(0, nrow=1E5, ncol=1E3))
t1 <- sapply(bigDF, class)
t2 <- for_soln(bigDF)

> head(t1)
    V1        V2        V3        V4        V5        V6 
"numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" 
> head(t2)
[1] "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric" "numeric"

> identical(t1, t2)
[1] FALSE
```

Doing an `Rprof` on `sapply` tells that all time spent is on `as.list.data.fraame`

```
Rprof()
t1 <- sapply(bigDF, class)
Rprof(NULL)
summaryRprof()

$by.self
                     self.time self.pct total.time total.pct
"as.list.data.frame"      1.16      100       1.16       100
```

You could speed up the operation by not asking for `as.list.data.frame`. Instead we could just query the class of each column of the `data.frame` directly as shown below. This is exactly equivalent to what you accomplish with the `for-loop` in fact.

```
t3 <- sapply(1:ncol(bigDF), function(idx) class(bigDF[[idx]]))
> identical(t2, t3)
[1] TRUE

microbenchmark(times=20, 
    sapply(bigDF, class),
    for_soln(bigDF),
    sapply(1:ncol(bigDF), function(idx) 
        class(bigDF[[idx]]))
)

Unit: milliseconds
        expr             min        lq       median       uq       max
1   for-soln (t2)     38.31545   39.45940   40.48152   43.05400  313.9484
2   sapply-new (t3)   18.51510   18.82293   19.87947   26.10541  261.5233
3   sapply-orig (t1) 952.94612 1075.38915 1159.49464 1204.52747 1484.1522
```

The difference in `t3` is that you create a list of length 1000 each with length 1. Whereas, in t1, its a list of length 1000, each with length 10000.

Comment: Ah, I see - `lapply` (which is called by `sapply`) does a check of `is.vector` on the object passed, which objects of class `data.frame` fail. Because of that, the object is converted to a list with `as.list` before the actual call to `.Internal(lapply)`, which is understandably slow. Thanks!

Comment: @Arun you should change class(bigDF[,idx]) to class(bigDF[[idx]]) in "new-sapply" solution

Comment: I guess the ultimate answer to this is: favor `*apply` calls of the form, eg, `lapply( 1:length(df), function(i) { <fun>(df[[i]]) } )` when working with a `data.frame`. Although (imo) it feels clunkier.